# Can't understand code/function call

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, typedef, function-calls

The declarations related to the question are are :

```
typedef void (*struct_c)(
    pid_t,  
    const uint_t *,
    struct_a,       
    struct_a,       
    void *);

void func1(struct_a s, struct_a e, struct_d init, struct_c range, struct_e fini, void *arg);
static void add_range(pid_t mgid, const uint_t *propids,struct_a s, struct_a e, void *arg);
```

There is a function call as follows:

```
func1(s, e,NULL,add_range, NULL, &ranges);
```

The argument add_range is a function name, there is no other variable by that name.

I don't understand how the function call func1 works and what are its arguments.

If you need more details,let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct_c` is a function pointer

`void func1(struct_a s, struct_a e, struct_d init, struct_c range, struct_e fini, void *arg);`
says

contains the function pointer in its 3rd argument i.e. `struct_c range` which matches the prototype of the function pointer

```
typedef void (*struct_c)(
    pid_t,  
    const uint_t *,
    struct_a,       
    struct_a,       
    void *);
```

and the prototype of the `add_range` function.

`static void add_range(pid_t mgid, const uint_t *propids,struct_a s, struct_a e, void *arg);`

In a trivial sense,

Function pointers are to functions, as,
integer pointers are to integers or such.

Comment: Horrible name for a function pointer.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes. Naming function pointers like they are struct typedefs, is very misleading.

Comment: if you added an edit in a follow-on section with an example using better naming, it may help to suppress the _Horrible name_ syndrome.

Answer (score 2):

`struct_c` is a type that is a pointer to function.

When calling `func1` the `add_range`, given that it has an appropriate signature, is implicitly converted to the required function pointer.

It is probably a poor choice of name though, I can only imagine there is legacy here.

Comment: I understood that, but my question is when you call func1 like this `func1(s, e,NULL,add_range, NULL, &ranges);`

What are the arguments of add_range? Shouldn't the call to func1 be like 
`func1(s, e,NULL,add_range(1,2,var_a,var_a,NULL), NULL, &ranges);`

Comment: @Anurag, nothing yet (as you call `func1`). The `func1` just wants a pointer to an appropriate function. It will presumably call the function with the arguments it calculates or has (from some or other source).